# Yii - Mailchimp - duplicate emails

Tags: yii, mailchimp

I am facing an issue which is a bit complicated.

Our website is integrated to CCAvenue payment gateway and we are also using mailchimp to send emails.

On successful transaction the user will be redirected back to our website and an email is sent to user and a CC is sent to our admin. From there the user is redirected to another page where the payment receipt is displayed.

The issue I am facing is, some times the user and admin is getting the copy of the same email many times. it can be 2 or 3 or even up to 10 duplicates/copies.

The duplicates comes with user details missing and the transaction amount messed up.

I am not able to reproduce it from my end till now. But many users are facing this issue.

What can be the reason for this?

thank you

Comment: If you send an email every time the person hits a particular page on your website, I'd guess that someone is hitting that page more times than you're expecting.

Comment: thanks... as i mentioned, the page from where email is sent, from there is redirected after sending email. So no way that user can hit that page again.

Comment: That's not guaranteed. if someone can trigger an email by hitting the same URL twice, you should always check to see if the email has already been sent. For example: if the destination page takes a bit to connect, the user might refresh their browser, which would cause them to hit the email sending URL twice.

Comment: Yes that is a valid point, but, just now i got a similar duplicate. but here the first email [the original one] was received at 7:10 PM and the duplicate was received after 9 minutes. So am not sure about that also. Also pressing the back button will not trigger emails again as we are checking that.

Comment: Well, there's not a lot of detail above to really help you. How is MailChimp sending emails about your payments? What's the actual mechanism? What code are you wanting help with? Since stackoverflow is for programming problems, there's typically code that goes along with it.

Comment: Hi Our system accepts a payment from the user and once the transaction is success, the receipt is sent to user via mandrill.  We are using Yii for development.

Comment: It sounds like your code is probably calling mandrill multiple times. You should try adding some logging around that call.

Comment: yes i will try that! thanks!